# Selenium Grid4 how to run test case in specific node

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm new to Selenium Grid 4 and trying to setting up the grid with Node & Hub Mode and run the test.For example, Below is my setup:

- Hub: linux
- Node A: windows chrome_v103 ip:192.168.1.1
- Node B: windows chrome_v103 ip:192.168.1.2

If I run a test case, sometimes it run on Node A, sometimes on Node B;How can I run a test in specific node, For example in node A, Not Node B